# sklearn ImportError: dll load failed, not enough memory (impossible)

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, importerror

I am an intern, continuing a topic of last year in ML.
But I have huge difficulties building a conda environment that is compatible with the scripts.
I am close to the goal, but I have an ImportError with sklearn:

`import sklearn`

And I receive:

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.`

This is quite surprising as I am using a 56GB of RAM workstation and only 10% is used.

Here is the list of packages and versions I am trying to use in my conda env:

- conda 4.10.3
- python 3.8
- numpy 1.19.5 (to avoid incompatibilities with    tensorflow)
- tensorflow 2.3.0
- asammdf 6.2.0
- pandas 1.3.1
- scikit-learn 0.22.2 (after having the same error with the latest version)
- numba 0.53.1

I hope my problem is clearly presented as it's my first post here, but I have found no information, so I hope you can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to use python version 3.7? There seem to be fewer incompatibility issues across these different modules there.

Comment: I finally managed to build an env on 3.7, and by changinf the order of installation of the packages after weird qt errors.
In details, the order was qt, pyqt, numpy 1.19.5, matplotlib, pandas, spyder, tensorflow 2.0, sklearn, asammdf, numba.